# Using the output voltage coming from the buck boost converter as an input supply for buck converter?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Can you tell me if this gonna work with no problem?? here's an example of what I'm talking about the LTC3119 is a buck boost converter and the other one is a buck converter. The buck-boost converter output voltage is around 12V and the buck converter output voltage is 5V[image]

Comment: It will. I don't know why you would do it, since the efficiency will be awful, but it will. Do you need `Rload` for the buck-boost, or only the next IC? Why not just take the 5 V from the input, directly? If you need the voltage to be toggled on/off, use a PMOS.

Comment: If something is really required u post a question. I see you are taking input 5V converting to 12V using buck-boost and then using Buck getting down to 5V. What are you going to achieve....

Comment: If the buck/boost can supply the power for both loads factoring in the buck's inefficiency, it should work.